# Can't get Google photos album contents using google photos api (and ColdFusion cfhttp)

Tags: coldfusion, google-oauth, google-photos, google-photos-api

I'll keep this short. I have OAuth working with the Google Photos API. I am able to return albums and media items but not album specific media items.

Below I've done three requests. The first two work while the third does not. 
Note: In the third request I've taken the albumID from the results returned in the first request.

```
<!--- This works --->
<cfhttp method="GET" charset="utf-8" url="https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums" result="res">
    <cfhttpparam name="Authorization" type="header" value="OAuth #application.oauth2.GetAccess_token()#" />
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#deserializeJSON(res.filecontent)#">

<!--- This works --->
<cfhttp method="GET" charset="utf-8" url="https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems" result="res">
    <cfhttpparam name="Authorization" type="header" value="OAuth #application.oauth2.GetAccess_token()#" />
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#deserializeJSON(res.filecontent)#">

<!--- This doesn't. I get a 404 for this --->
<cfhttp method="POST" charset="utf-8" url="https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search" result="res">
    <cfhttpparam name="Authorization" type="header" value="OAuth #application.oauth2.GetAccess_token()#" />
    <cfhttpparam name="albumId" type="formfield" value="AHeArAbj3EfLJqs23FHD9SWuReCaaPA0VBZxw6HNwL752bJr5X882_ZJnitk7kjZJwtzXvrw6hp2" />
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#res#">
```

This is the result I get for the last request;
[image]

What is wrong with the last request I am making? I am trying to use this API call: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/search

Comment: What is the response that you are getting for the last request?

Comment: Hi @RRK. Edited my question above with a photo. Basically a 404!

Comment: Alle the samples on the developers page you links contain a JSON payload in the request. You are sending your albumID as formfield.

Comment: I tried testing this using https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/search and the URL that was called was `https://content-photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAa8yy0GdcGPHdtD083HiGGx_S0vMPScDM`. Notice the `content-`